# sql minimum from one column, unique for another column group by a third

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query where I'm selecting from three tables

```
select 
    min(t.ReminderDt) as 'rem dt',  
    m.Group_Id, m.AccountNumber 
from 
    ACE_AccsLevelTran t, ACE_AccsLevelMaster m 
where 
    t.MasterAccNumber = m.AccountNumber 
group by  
    m.Group_Id, m.AccountNumber;
```

This results in:

```
rem dt | Group_Id| AccountNumber
--------------------------------    
2/8/2013 | 3 | 4216985
2/22/2013 | 4 | 4274863
2/7/2013 | 3 | 4366383
2/28/2013 | 4 | 7151712
```

How do I get the rows for only the minimum dates for 3 and 4 like the result -

```
2/7/2013 | 3 | 4366383
2/22/2013 | 4 | 4274863
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the account_number from the group by and surround it with `min()` or `max()` on the `select` line:

```
select min(t.ReminderDt) as 'rem dt',  m.Group_Id, min(m.AccountNumber)
from ACE_AccsLevelTran t,     ACE_AccsLevelMaster m 
where t.MasterAccNumber=m.AccountNumber
group by  m.Group_Id
```

That returns an arbitrary account number.  To get the *row* with the minimum value, the best way is to use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (select t.ReminderDt) as 'rem dt',  m.Group_Id, m.AccountNumber,
            row_number() over (partition by group_id order by reminderdt desc) as seqnum
      from ACE_AccsLevelTran t join ACE_AccsLevelMaster m 
           on t.MasterAccNumber=m.AccountNumber
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Also, you should learn ANSI standard JOIN syntax, as used in this query.

Answer (score -1):

If your accountNumber is Unique too you can do it in this way:

```
Select m.Group_Id ,X.MinReminderDT,m.AccountNumber 
from ACE_AccsLevelMaster m join(
select min(t.ReminderDt) as MinReminderDT,t.MasterAccNumber
from ACE_AccsLevelTran t
Group By t.MasterAccNumber) X on X.MasterAccNumber=m.AccountNumber
```

Comment: this will not work as there are mutiple account numbers for a group id.